# Python module PyQt5 installation problem on arm64 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pyqt5, arm64, pyenv

I have arm64 system and ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. I try to install python pyqt5 on
it by pip command. Its shows

*AttributeError: module ‘sipbuild.api’ has no attribute ‘prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel’*
error.
I am using pyenv. I tried many others way, but did not worked

Comment: which version of pip, python and pyqt5 have you installed are you trying to install?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.